# Windows 2019 OpenVPN Server not routing local LAN

Tags: windows, vpn, routing, openvpn, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to get my OpenVPN server on Windows Server 2019 to route traffic properly to the internal LAN, and so far I can't get it to work at all,  being unable ping the server's LAN IP or any other IPs within the LAN. I've tried using NetHack and couldn't get that to work (undid this for now), and I also enabled IP forwarding with no luck either.

- The network setup is simple: 
   Server: `192.168.44.2` 
   Gateway: `192.168.44.254` [USG Pro 4] 
   LAN: `192.168.44.0/24` 
   VPN: `192.168.10.0/24`
- `server.conf`:

  ```
  local 192.168.44.2
  port 1194
  proto udp4
  dev tun
  ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
  cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\server.crt"
  key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\server.key"  
  dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\dh.pem"
  topology subnet
  server 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
  ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
  route-method exe
  route-delay
  push "route 192.168.44.0 255.255.255.0"
  push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
  client-to-client
  duplicate-cn
  keepalive 10 120
  cipher AES-256-GCM
  persist-key
  persist-tun
  status openvpn-status.log
  verb 3
  explicit-exit-notify 1
  client-config-dir "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ccd"
  ifconfig-pool-persist "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\log\\ipp.txt" 5
  ```
- `client.conf`:

  ```
  client
  dev tun
  proto udp
  remote **.**.**.** 1194
  resolv-retry infinite
  nobind
  persist-key
  persist-tun
  remote-cert-tls server
  cipher AES-256-CBC
  verb 3
  route 192.168.44.0 255.255.255.0
  ```
- Server routing table:

  ```
  IPv4 Route Table
  ===========================================================================
  Active Routes:
  Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
            0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   192.168.44.254     192.168.44.2    281
          127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
          127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
    127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
       192.168.10.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.44.2     26
     192.168.10.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.44.2    281
       192.168.44.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.44.2    281
       192.168.44.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.137.1     26
       192.168.44.2  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.44.2    281
     192.168.44.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.44.2    281
     192.168.44.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    281
      192.168.137.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.137.1    281
      192.168.137.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    281
    192.168.137.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    281
          224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
          224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.137.1    281
          224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.44.2    281
    255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
    255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    281
    255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.44.2    281
  ```
- Client Routing Table:

  ```
  IPv4 Route Table
  ===========================================================================
  Active Routes:
  Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
            0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.140     25
          127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
          127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
    127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.140    281
      192.168.1.140  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.140    281
      192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.140    281
       192.168.10.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.10.2    281
       192.168.10.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.10.1     192.168.10.2     25
       192.168.10.2  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.10.2    281
     192.168.10.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.10.2    281
       192.168.44.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.10.1     192.168.10.2     25
          224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
          224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.10.2    281
          224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.140    281
    255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
    255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.10.2    281
    255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.140    281
  ===========================================================================
  ```

**Solution**
@JW0194
Remove route from client config (it's already pushed). If that doesn't resolve, add to server config: push dhcp-option DNS 192.168.44.254 (if .254 is the router's LAN interface) & push dhcp-option WINS 192.168.44.254

Comment: Remove `route` from client config (it's already pushed). If that doesn't resolve, add to server config: `push dhcp-option DNS 192.168.44.254` _(if `.254` is the router's LAN interface)_ & `push dhcp-option WINS 192.168.44.254`. General FYI: AES256 is pointless since AES128 will remain uncrackable until at least 2030 _(all it's doing is slowing throughput to a crawl)_; You're lacking HMAC authentication via `auth SHA512` and `tls-crypt`; TLS EC ciphers are more efficient; `duplicate-cn` isn't secure. Tuned config [examples](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN)

Comment: @JW0914 thanks this fixed it